# Lazy-evaluation of a "#{}"-string in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, eval

I started to put print-statements throughout my code. So as not to clutter up the output, I did something like:

```
dputs LEVEL, "string"
```

where `LEVEL` is 0 for errors, 1 for important .. 5 for verbose and is compared to `DEBUG_LEVEL`. Now my problem is, that in a statement like:

```
dputs 5, "#{big_class.inspect}"
```

the string is always evaluated, also if I set `DEBUG_LEVEL` to 1. And this evaluation can take a long time. My favourite solution would be something like:

```
dputs 5, '#{big_class.inspect}'
```

and then evaluate the string if desired. But I don't manage to get the string in a form I can evaluate. So the only think I could come up with is:

```
dputs( 5 ){ "#{big_class.inspect}" }
```

but this looks just ugly. So how can I evaluate a '#{}' string?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use the built in [Logger class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) instead of re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: Agreed. Use Logger, or the Syslog functionality. Don't reinvent wheels.

Comment: With Logger, I would have to map the "severity" to my "debug-levels", which is not too nice, IMHO. And the problem with the "too many caracters" to write the block remains the same... So I'd still like being able to evaluate `'#{big_class.inspect}'`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can dodge the ugly there. The interpolation happens before the call to dputs unless you put it inside a block, which postpones it until dputs evaluates it. I don't know where dputs comes from, so I'm not sure what its semantics are, but my guess is the block would get you the lazy evaluation you want. Not pretty, but it does the job.

Comment: Dputs is a simple module I wrote, which does a nice printing of debugging messages, including the class and method and formatting of very long lines into multiple, indented lines.

Answer (score 6):

You could do this by having `dputs` use [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) (via [`%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25)). That way it can decide not to build the interpolated string unless it knows it's going to print it:

```
def dputs(level, format_str, *vars)
  puts(format_str % vars) if level <= LEVEL
end

LEVEL = 5
name = 'Andrew'
dputs 5, 'hello %s', name
#=> hello Andrew
```

Or, as you suggest, you can pass a block which would defer the interpolation till the block actually runs:

```
def dputs(level, &string)
  raise ArgumentError.new('block required') unless block_given?
  puts string.call if level <= LEVEL
end
```

Comment: The idea is to have as few caracters as possible - remember, be lazy ;) So I prefer writing in single quotes `dputs 5, 'long debugging#{bigclass.inspect}'` over `dputs 5, "long debugging %s", bigclass.inspect`. I'm not even sure the latter will not evaluate anyway!

Comment: I just checked, the sprintf-example you give above evaluates in every case... So I'm back to the block. But I'm sure there is a way to evaluate `'#{big_class.inspect}'`!

Comment: It will evaluate the `inspect`, of course, but not the interpolation. You may be "sure" there's a way to get the syntax and behavior you want, but there's not.

Comment: What is the difference of "evaluate" and "interpolate"?

Comment: @ineiti Interpolation is the `#{}` syntax within a string.

Comment: As I stated in the question, the problem is the evaluation of the inspect which is done all over in `DEBUG_LEVEL` 5 but which takes time that I don't want to spend in a production-code with `DEBUG_LEVEL`of 1 or 0...

Answer (score 2):

I think it's of no value whatsoever, but I just came up with:

```
2.3.1 :001 > s = '#{a}'
 => "\#{a}"
2.3.1 :002 > a = 1
 => 1
2.3.1 :003 > instance_eval s.inspect.gsub('\\', '')
 => "1"
2.3.1 :004 > s = 'Hello #{a} and #{a+1}!'
 => "Hello \#{a} and \#{a+1}!"
2.3.1 :005 > instance_eval s.inspect.gsub('\\', '')
 => "Hello 1 and 2!"
```

Don't use that in production :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, obviously I was just too lazy. I thought there must be a more clean way to do this, Ruby being the best programming language and all ;) To evaluate a string like

```
a = '#{1+1} some text #{big_class.inspect}'
```

only when needed, I didn't find a better way than going through the string and **eval** all "#{}" encountered:

```
str = ""
"#{b}\#{}".scan( /(.*?)(#\{[^\}]*\})/ ){
  str += $1
  str += eval( $2[2..-2] ).to_s
}
```

if you're not into clarity, you can get rid of the temporary-variable **str**:

```
"#{b}\#{}".scan( /(.*?)(#\{[^\}]*\})/ ).collect{|c|
  c[0] + eval( c[1][2..-2] ).to_s
}.join
```

The String.scan-method goes through every '#{}'-block, as there might be more than one, evaluating it (the **2..-2** cuts out the "#{" and "}") and putting it together with the rest of the string.

For the corner-case of the string not ending with a '#{}'-block, an empty block is added, just to be sure.

But well, after being some years in Ruby, this still feels clunky and C-ish. Perhaps it's time to learn a new language!

Comment: But this in fact evaluates the variables in the wrong context, so it doesn't work. So I think I give my vote to Mike Larsen who says I can't dodge the ugly. Some months later now and I got already used to the new syntax ;)